# How to add 3D-Text to a video programmatically

Tags: opengl, video, text, 3d, ffmpeg

I'm looking for a fast, efficient solution to add text to a video. I tried the CLI from ffmpeg but I think it only lets me add 2D-Text. I want to be able to create Text and /or images and Rotate / Skew them in "3D-Space".

Is this possible via CLI of some video processing tools or do I have to get into OpenCV etc.?

Comment: OpenCV just came up in my mind but it's definitly too much.

Comment: just pre-render it from your fav. 3d renderer. blender,max,maya,meshlab,whatever.

Comment: The final solution should be a Server-Processing triggered by a JSP-Application. Is this still possible with blender?

Comment: Render your 3d text to texture then overlay your video footage using FFMPEG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.

I will go with this:

- Create a Textblock in ImageMagick and Distort it into the 3D Space (e.g. http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective)
- Export from ImageMagick to a ImageFormat with Alphachannel (e.g. PNG / TGA)
- Overlay the image over the video using CLI from FFMPEG
- (e.g. http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/PICTURE-IN-PICTURE-effect-using-FFMPEG)